# Leaflet - How to show feature properties in a box that is not a popup?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, features, markers

Popup giving features properties are interesting but I would like to make a side bar where properties of a clicked feature would show.

I've got the traditional code for displaying geojson features using jquery :

```
 $.getJSON("${resourcesFolderName}/VergueParis.geojson",function(data){
        //Def icons
        var siteIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: '${resourcesFolderName}/eye.svg',
            iconSize: [30,30]
        }); 
        var siteIcon2 = L.icon({
            iconUrl: '${resourcesFolderName}/eye2.svg',
            iconSize: [30,30]
        });
        var siteIcon3 = L.icon({
            iconUrl: '${resourcesFolderName}/eye3.svg',
            iconSize: [30,30]
        });

        L.geoJson(data  ,{
            pointToLayer: function(feature,latlng){
             var marker = L.marker(latlng,{icon: siteIcon});
            marker.bindPopup('<img src="'+ feature.properties.Image +'" style="width:100%;height:100%;">'+ '<br/>' +'<img src="${resourcesFolderName}/Filet.svg" style="width:221px;height:10px;">' + '<br/>' + feature.properties.Titre + '<br/>' + feature.properties.Annee);
            return marker; 
            return L.marker(latlng,{icon: siteIcon});
            },
            //Change icon on Rollover
            onEachFeature: function(feature,layer)
            {
            layer.on("mouseover",function(e){
                layer.setIcon(siteIcon2)
            });
            layer.on("mouseout",function(e){
                layer.setIcon(siteIcon)
            });
            //End change on rollover
            }
        }).addTo(hypeDocument.map).on('click', markerOnClick);
    });
```

And the associated markerOnClick function :

```
function markerOnClick(e) { 
        alert("hi. you clicked the marker at " + e.latlng);
        var newinnerContent = 'Title of the feature :';
        hypeDocument.getElementById("Rectangle").innerHTML = newinnerContent;
        hypeDocument.continueTimelineNamed('Rectangle', hypeDocument.kDirectionForward)
    };
```

Note : the 'Hype' reference relates to a software i'm using to create my map.

Alert function works and I'd like to display the feature property "Titre" just after the above phrase "Title of the feature :"

I tried different approaches but nothing works.

Any idea would be welcome.

Comment: Are there any error messages in the console (Developer Tools of your browser)?

Comment: PS.: [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (`${resourcesFolderName}`) need enclosing back ticks (`\``) rather than quotes.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Changed the back ticks but it still doesn't work. And the console doesn't show any problem.

Answer (score 4):

I added a sidebar in html, and in the sidebar, placed an html table, I gave the cells an ID so I could place data from a click in them.

```
  <div class="sidebar">
<p style="text-align:center; font-size: 24px; color:#175B81; font-weight:bold; "> Baseball</p>   
            <table  style="width:90%; ">
            <tr>
            <td id='pict' ALIGN='center'; > </td>
            <td id='pict2' ALIGN='center';> </td>
            </tr>
            </table></br> </br>

            <table  style="width:90%">
              <tr>
              <th align="left">League</th>
              <td id='f1'></td>
              </tr> <tr>
              <th align="left">Team</th>
              <td id='f2'></td></tr>
              <tr>
             <th align="left">Address</th>
              <td id='f3'></td>
              </tr> <tr>
```

Next in my onEachFeature function, I placed an on-click function, to take the feature attributes and place them into the appropriate cell by ID>

```
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {

                        layer.on('click', function (e) {

                            // get coordinates from GeoJSON
                            var coords = e.target.feature.geometry.coordinates
                            //pass coords to function to create marker.(Yellow circle)
                            onMapClick(coords);

                            //place attributes in panel table.
                                var fieldA=document.getElementById('pict');
                                fieldA.innerHTML='<img src="' +e.target.feature.properties.Logo +'">';
                                var fieldB=document.getElementById('pict2');
                                fieldB.innerHTML='<img src="' +e.target.feature.properties.LeagueLogo +'">';

                                var field1=document.getElementById('f1');
                                field1.innerHTML=e.target.feature.properties.League;
                                var field2=document.getElementById('f2');
                                field2.innerHTML=e.target.feature.properties.Team;
                                var field3=document.getElementById('f3');
```

If you like JQuery you can replace some of the above code with something like this:

```
$('#f1').html(e.target.feature.properties.League);
```

Below is a working example.

http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/baseball/BaseballPanel.html

Comment: Thanks Bill ! I try to adapt your code but with no result so far.

Comment: You had it firing on a marker click function, try using/putting the layer on click in the onEachFeature function.That gets the specific feature you clicked on and sends it's attributes.    getElementById("Rectangle").innerHTM  "Rectangle" is an HTML ID right? A div or span tag with that ID?  It's not the feature.

Comment: Well, I'm not that good in JS. "Rectangle" is the the ID, yes. Should I put layerOnClick instead of markerOnClick ? How should my code look like ?

Comment: Look at my example link, right clcik on the page and view source. The html and JS are all there. My GeoJSON file is here. http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/baseball/BaseBallFinal.json is you save it as BaseBallFinal.json and toss it in the same folder as the html file, it should work. The" layer.on('click', function (e) {" method work for markers , polygons, and polyline features.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, Bill, thank you for all your good advice. But I'm afraid I'm terrible at coding. Your code is beautiful but with a different logic that the part of mine that works so far. I'd like to keep what I have and adapt your layer click to it.

Comment: Put this in your onEachFeature and test it.  layer.on('click', function (e) {
document.getElementById("Rectangle").innerHTML(e.target.feature.properties.Annee);
}

Comment: Still no effect. Actually, it appears that I may already have a layer.on click function at the end of my geojson display : }).addTo(hypeDocument.map).on('click', markerOnClick);

Comment: It works ! Thanks you !! I made a little modification to your line at the very end (remove () and add =) : hypeDocument.getElementById("Rectangle2").innerHTML = "test"+e.target.feature.properties.Titre

Comment: @BillChappell The tiles for OSM B&W in your example do not load, FYI.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the Titre in the function `onMarkerClick` by referring to `e.target.feature.properties.Titre` (`target` is the marker).

Your updated function would look like this:

```
function markerOnClick(e) { 
    ...
    var newinnerContent = 'Title of the feature : ' + e.target.feature.properties.Titre;
    ...
};
```

PS.: I have just read the comments to [Bill Chapell](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/20255/bill-chappell)'s answer where you already have figured it out. My answer should be seen as a short cut.

Comment: Tank you Stefan